# Retrieving text formatting in a text file created from a string with FileOutputStream

Tags: java

i'm generating a text paragraph like this:

```
>1.    this is the first line 
>1.    this is the second line
>1.    this is the third line
>1.    this is the fourth line
```

and then storing that in a string

Then I want to output this string to a zipped text document, it all works but the formatting isn't there when I open the text file created with FileOutputStream, Do you know how I can retrieve the formatting?

code:

```
try
{
        String toZip = file.toString();

DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.zip")));   
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(dos);


        byte[] b = toZip.getBytes("UTF8");
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("TheFirstFile.txt");
        System.out.println("Zipping.." + entry.getName());                      
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);        
        zos.write(b, 0, b.length);

        dos.close();
        zos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MyException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

had problems posting code here..
Test Program:

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class TestZip {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("c:\\TEMP\\tests.txt"),"UTF-8"));
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

        String line = br.readLine();

        try
        {
            while(line != null)
            {  
                if(line != null)
                {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                line=br.readLine();
            }

            String data = buffer.toString();
            br.close();

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("c:\\TEMP\\ZippedFile.zip"));
            ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(bos);


            System.out.println(data);

            byte[] b = data.getBytes();
            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("TheData.txt");
            System.out.println("Zipping.." + entry.getName());                      
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);        
            zos.write(b, 0, b.length);

            zos.closeEntry();
            zos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

The text is margined to how I want it when I print it out on the console, when I check the zipped text file, the text is all on one line.

console output:
[image: console print result]

text file result:
[image: result]

I wanted it to appear in the text file exactly how it prints in the console.

I've never coded a program before which can read a zipped text file, but I tried..

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


public class TestUnzip {


    public static void main (String[] args) { 

        String unzip = ""; 

        try  
        { 
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:\\TEMP\\ZippedFile.zip"); 
            ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
            ZipEntry ze; 

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];


            ze = zin.getNextEntry();

            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) 
            { 
                    if (zin.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length) != -1) 
                    {
                        unzip = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("error");
                    }

                    ze = zin.getNextEntry();
            } 


            System.out.println(unzip.toString());

            zin.closeEntry();
            zin.close();
        } 
        catch(Exception e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      } 
}
```

Comment: What do you call the formatting? What do you expect to get and what do you get instead? And how do you read the file? Provide an SSCCE.

Comment: the code is kind of rough since i'm using about 5 different classes for the full program (and didn't want to post the entire thing here, too long), basically i'm making a gui and using JFileChooser to read 3 text files and display the contents in text components, then I convert the imported files to strings to do other operations on the text files

Comment: That's precisely why you should create and post an SSCCE.

Comment: The first letter in SSCCE means "short". You shouldn't have any problem posting an SSCCE here. It should just create a zip file and read it. No GUI, nothing. And you sill haven't explained your problem: what do you mean by "the formatting". Plain text doesn't have any formatting, by definition.

Comment: Forget about the code you have. Create a simple, console based program which, from the main method, creates a zip file containing a multi-line text file entry, and then reads it back. And provide the output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Notepad is expecting windows line termination.
`\r\n`, not just `\n`

Try opening it in another editor, like Notepad++;

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline